# Can we relate the character of the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets $G/\langle g_i\rangle$ to the number of cycles of $g_i$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters, permutation-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group generated by permutations $g_1,\dots,g_s$ such that $g_1g_2\cdots g_s$ is the identity permutation.

The corresponding Hurwitz representation $V_{\text{Hur}}$ has character $$\chi_{\text{Hur}}=(s-2)
\chi_{\text{reg}}-\sum_i\chi_{g_i}+2,$$ where $\chi_{\text{reg}}$ is the regular representation of $G$ and $\chi_{g_i}$ is the character of the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets $G/\langle g_i\rangle.$
(For a full definition, see Section 3.1 of [*Realization of Primitive Branched Coverings over
Closed Surfaces Following the Hurwitz Approach*](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.2478/BF02476007/html?lang=en) Note that $\chi_{\text{Hur}}(\text{id})$ gives the dimension of the Hurwitz representation $\chi_{\text{Hur}}(\text{id})=\text{dim}V_{\text{Hur}}$.

This is awfully similar to the relation given in the Bull. LMS paper *[A Necessary Condition for Transitivity of a Finite Permutation Group](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/20.3.235)*, where Conder and McKay prove that if a permutation group $G$ acts transitively on a set $\Omega$ of order $n$, then $n(s-2)-\sum_i c_i+2,$ where $c_i$ is the number of cycles of the generator $g_i$, is a non-negative even integer. (By "cycles," they mean 1-cycles/fixed points, 2-cycles, 3-cycles, &c.) We can simply think of the action of $G$ on itself to frame the problem in this second scenario, since then $\chi_{\text{reg}}(\text{id})=n$.

What, then, is the analog of the $\chi_{g_i}$ in terms of the $c_i$?

Comment: What is a Hurwitz representation?

Comment: Question edited with a source for the definition.

Comment: $\chi_{Hur}(1) = n(s-2) - \sum_{i} c_i + 2$ if $\Omega$ is the regular permutation action of $G$. (Each $g \in G$ acts on $\Omega = G$ with $|G|/|g|$ cycles of length $|g|$.) I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Yes; then this is also the dimension of the Hurwitz representation $V_{\text{Hur}}=\chi_{\text{Hur}}(\text{id})$.

Comment: But how can each $g\in G$ act on $\Omega=G$ with $|G|/|g|$ cycles of length $|g|$? For the identity, this statement says $\text{id}$ acts on $G$ with one cycle of length $|G|$, when $\text{id}$ actually acts on $G$ with $|G|$ cycles of length one. @testaccount

Comment: $|g|$ is the order of $g$, so $|\textrm{id}|=1$ and the formula is correct in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hurwitz representation's existence implies the inequality $(s-2) n - \sum_i c_i + 2\geq 0$ in general - there is no need to restrict to the case of $G$ acting on itself.

If $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$ then $\Omega \cong G/H$ for a subgroup $H$ of $G$. The dimension of the $H$-invariant subspace of the Hurwitz representation is $\frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h\in H} \chi_{\textrm{Hur}}(h)$ so we have

$$0 \leq \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h\in H} \chi_{\textrm{Hur}}(h)= (s-2) \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h\in H} \chi_{\textrm{reg}}(h) - \sum_i \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h\in H} \chi_{g_i}(h)+2$$

Now $$\chi_{\textrm{reg}}(h)= \begin{cases} G & \textrm{if } h=\textrm{id} \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ so $$\frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h\in H} \chi_{\textrm{reg}}(h) = \frac{1}{|H|} |G|= |\Omega| =n$$

and $ \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h\in H} \chi_{g_i}(h)$ is the dimension of the space of $H$-invariant functions on the cosets $G/\langle g_i \rangle$ which is the number of double cosets $H \backslash G / \langle g_i \rangle$ which is the number of orbits of $g_i$ on $G/H =\Omega$ which is the number of cycles of $G$ acting on $\Omega$. Thus

$$ 0 \leq (s-2) n - \sum_i c_i + 2$$

as desired.

In the case $G$ acting on itself, so $H$ is the identity, this specializes to the inequality that the dimension of the Hurwitz representation is nonnegative, as you suspected.